# Saving csv file after every iteration without overwriting while running python script in delayed mode

Tags: python

Currently, I am picking up data from a company web site and getting a CSV file `export.csv`. Each time I run the script I am getting a new CSV file that overwrites the previous one. This is a company's script I am using:

```
import requests


URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?[My filters]&auth=my_name@yahoo.com"

response = requests.get(URL)

open("export.csv", "wb").write(response.content)
```

The script works fine, but I need some changes in order to get output that I need.

First, I would like to get a new csv file saved with different name (example: `export0.csv`/`export1.csv`/`export2.csv` and so on) each time script finishes its run.

So, each run should generate a new CSV file that holds a new name (possibly with the number associated with the number of runs). The number of total runs should be also limited (with limits easy to change ), and runs should be set up for a delayed period of time (for example: to run every 5 min until the program reaches the total number of runs).

In fact, I am new to Python, and recently I have installed Python version 3.10.11.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the number of files already saved and generate a new name to save with.

Maybe this will help

```
import requests
import glob

# Check the file location to find the number of csv already save 
saving_path = path/to/location
num_file = len(glob.glob(saving_path))

URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?[My filters]&auth=my_name@yahoo.com"
next_file_name = f"export{num_file+1}.csv"
response = requests.get(URL)

open(next_file_name, "wb").write(response.content)
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your instruction;here is my code:

Comment: import requests
import glob

saving_path = path/to/'C:\Users\Stosic Family\Python' 
num_file = len(glob.glob(saving_path))

URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?[My filters]]&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
next_file_name = f"export{num_file+1}.csv"
response = requests.get(URL)

open(next_file_name, "wb").write(response.content)

Comment: but, unfortunately didn't work. I got the following message:

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) "unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \ UXXXXXXX escape . Any idea what went wrong ? Thank you

Comment: if path/to/ should not be there

Comment: I changed the code into new one, following instruction:

Comment: import requests
import glob

saving_path = "C:\Users\Stosic Family\Python\export.csv" 
num_file = len(glob.glob(saving_path))

URL = "https:/company name.com/export.ashx?[My filters]&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
next_file_name = f"export{num_file+1}.csv"
response = requests.get(URL)

open(next_file_name, "wb").write(response.content)

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) "unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated

Comment: Still have the same Syntax error message; any idea ?

Comment: Oh I see why you get the error change it to "C:\Users\Stosic Family\Python\export.csv" to "C:\\Users\\Stosic Family\\Python\\export.csv". it is consider \xxx as a unicode for system functions. Like escape

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template that might help:

```
import time

delay = 1 #second
max_writes = 10

for i in range(max_writes):
    with open(f"file_{i}.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(i)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

This just writes text to the files (the range count), but you can easily substitute in your current code for writing out a .csv. Note the newer syntax for writing a file, which will close it automatically for you.

Combining it with your code would result in something like...

```
import time
import requests

delay = 10 #seconds
max_writes = 10

for i, url in enumerate(urls): # Assuming you have a list of URLs to request data from
    for j in range(max_writes):
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.ok:
            with open(f"file_{i}.csv", 'w') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
            break
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Hi, your code works fine and creates csv files under different names and time delayed is also OK, however any idea how can I put your code into mine to reflect the data pulled out from the web ? So far, I am still getting my export file ( export.csv ) with data, however new csv files created using your code are empty ( don't have a data , only one number in column A ) Any idea how can we pair these two codes to work together ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Jason, yes I finally got what I want following your instruction, however some modification to the code were required. Here is the code that writes me back as csv files, every 5 minutes data from the web:

Comment: import time
import requests

delay = 300
max_writes =11

URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?[my filters]=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"

for i in range(max_writes):
    response = requests.get(URL)
    if response.ok:
        with open(f"export_{i+1}.csv", 'wb') as file:
             file.write(response.content)
       
    time.sleep(delay)

Comment: Currently, I am getting csv files in one directory, can I save them in another, directly in excel workbook ( each csv files should go into separate tab ) ? Thank you

Comment: Best thanks would be accepting the answer for some points, bro! :)